# Term For Average Of Same Month Of Previous Years

Tags: vocabulary

My spreadsheet displays an amount for a particular month, say March. What term would describe the average of all March entries over the past years for which I have data? Similar Months? Like Months? etc.

Answer (score 2):

I use **Year-on-Year** (YOY). [Investipedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/y/year-over-year.asp) uses Year-over-Year.

It is defined there as:

> Year over year (YOY) is a method of evaluating two or more measured events to compare the results at one time period with those of a comparable time period on an annualized basis.

Comment: Doesn't "March year-on-year" mean the average of all data in years April–March, rather than the collection of all Marches?

Answer (score 0):

The less-than-ideal *seasonal* is often used to get the point across, even though a month isn't a season -  March 2017 vs seasonal monthly average of past 10 years. Mathematically, this could mean either the annual sales were calculated and a seasonal index applied for March, or as you have described, just using the data from previous Marches. The former method allows multiple indexes to be applied.

https://mathsfm234.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/seasonal-indices.doc